# Lost connection to MySQL server during query with UNION

Tags: mysql

i am getting error `Lost connection to MySQL server during query` with `UNION` query bellow.

```
select * 
from `dealers` 
where   exists ((
            select * 
            from `cars` 
            where `dealers`.`id` = `cars`.`dealer_id` 
               and exists (select * 
                           from `dealers` 
                           where `cars`.`dealer_id` = `dealers`.`id`)  
               and `dealer_id` = 27 
               order by `price` asc)

            union (select * 
                   from `cars` 
                   where `dealers`.`id` = `cars`.`dealer_id` 
                   and exists (select * 
                               from `dealers` 
                               where `cars`.`dealer_id` = `dealers`.`id`) 
                               and `dealer_id` != 27 
                               order by `price` desc)) 

order by `dealers`.`name` asc
```

Strange thing is that if i remove the last line entirely or if i sort by `id` instead of `name` it works fine.

Any ideas what could possibly be wrong with this?

Comment: order by `price` desc)) **AS TABLE_TMP** order by `dealers`.`name` asc

Comment: That results to `You have an error in your SQL syntax`